# Correct representation of DOM in LWC?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lwc-dom, shadow-dom

Sharing my visual understanding of DOM.

Please let me know if this is correct?

Also please do share more useful material or your viewpoints. Will be helpful.

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the browser's point of view, this is correct. The only other thing you might not be aware of is the [Virtual DOM](https://github.com/snabbdom/snabbdom/). The runtime generates components and places them in to the Virtual DOM, which is then translated into real DOM elements. However, that's merely technical details. If you understand shadow boundaries, shadow DOM, etc, that is sufficient for understanding how events, styling, and API access works.